# Application Crashes when using more rectangle filling visual brush

Tags: c#, wpf

i am creating a video player where i need to use nearly 50 rectangle to display the same video

using visual brush. issue is it is playing some times without crashing most of the time application crashes and shows

fault module  wpfgfx_v0400.dll and there is a fall in frame rate in filled rectangles.

thank you.

Code:

```
    string SourceFile;
    MediaElement Element = new MediaElement();
    public void mediaaaaa( string PathFile)
    {

        SourceFile = PathFile;

        Element.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;

        Element.BeginInit();


        Element.Source = new Uri(PathFile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        Element.EndInit();
        Element.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Close;


        StackPanel dd = new StackPanel();
        dd.Children.Add(Element);

        Element.MediaEnded += new RoutedEventHandler(Element_MediaEnded);

        WrapPanel wrap = new WrapPanel();

        foreach (MediaElement item in dd.Children)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
          Rectangle Vis = new Rectangle();
          Vis.Fill = new VisualBrush(item);
                Vis.Width = 200;
                Vis.Height = 200;
                wrap.Children.Add(Vis);    
            }

        }

        canvas.Children.Clear();
        canvas.Children.Add(wrap);

    }

    void Element_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Element.Source = new Uri(SourceFile);
    }
```

Comment: It will be hard to say what's wrong without seeing some code

Comment: Please check the code